# Grass Root Live wallpaper not working for HoneyComb, Android

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

When I try to launch the Grass Root Live wall paper,I get the following error message in the window and wallpaper is never launched.

Error Message :"Android Live Wallpapers (process com.android.wallpaper) has stopped unexpectedly"

The root cause of this issue is a Null pointer exception at line 146 of frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/renderscript/AllocationAdapter.java.This issue lies with Google's code. If anyone is aware of anything related to this, kindly help! Is anybody is aware of any patch from google which can fix this?

Note : This is a generic HoneyComb issue.

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? Does it continue to be a problem on multiple devices? Is this tied to one manufacturer or one processor or any other single commonality? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other live wallpapers on your phone? If they work, the problem might be with this particular live wallpaper and not your Android installation.

If you have a rooted phone, you can try and fix app permissions or try updating your ROM. If not, you can try to install an update for your ROM(if there is one).

There is no other way that I can think of. You would rarely have to fix something in the Android code to solve a problem that only you are having.

Comment: This is not only my issue, this is generic Honeycomb issue and other live wallpapers are working, this is an HoneyComb Android code problem.

Comment: Then, you might have to wait for an official fix from your device manufacturer. (Sorry about earlier, I said you were on a phone. I presume you are on a tablet.)